# javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException: Username token required. Cannot find in the security header in Jdeveloper 10.1.3

Tags: web-services, jdeveloper

If I try to consume `Webservices` in `Jdeveloper 10.1.3` i am getting below exception in console. Even if we are giving username and password the same error happened again. But i don't know how to solve this exception.

```
javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException: Username token required. 
                                       Cannot find in the security header
at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._raiseFault(StreamingSender.java:555)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._sendImpl(StreamingSender.java:396)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._send(StreamingSender.java:112)
at rightnowproject.proxy.runtime.RightNowSyncBinding_Stub.queryCSV
                                    (RightNowSyncBinding_Stub.java:1423)
at rightnowproject.proxy.RightNowSyncPortClient.queryCSV(RightNowSyncPortClient.java:101)
at rightnowproject.proxy.RightNowSyncPortClient.main(RightNowSyncPortClient.java:61)
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

Comment: I think your web service expecting credentials in soap header. you must be providing it in different way.

Comment: Exactly, but the problem is i am not aware of providing soap header in this jdeveloper.

Comment: Any one can tell me how to add security header in Jdeveloper 10.1.3?.